# How to get reliably a complete sessionInfo in mclapply/pbmclapply?

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, reproducible-research, mclapply

I'm using `pbmcapply::pbmclapply` (in `Rscript`, i.e. non-interactive if that matters) to see a progress bar during multthreading. Now I tried to pass `sessionInfo()` as an attribute and noticed that *"other attached packages"* and *"loaded via a namespace (and not attached)"* are not correctly shown. What's the reason for this? Can it be fixed? How?

#### Example

As this does not seem to depend on whether multiple cores are used, we can use `mc.cores=1L` in the examples (and thus also make it available under Windows).

```
f1 <- \(x) {
  pbmcapply::pbmclapply(x, \(x) {
    library(Matrix)
    var(MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, rep(0, 2), matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)))
  }, mc.cores=1L)
  `attr<-`(x, 's_info', sessionInfo())
}

f2 <- \(x) {
  parallel::mclapply(x, \(x) {
    library(Matrix)
    var(MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, rep(0, 2), matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)))
  }, mc.cores=1L)
  `attr<-`(x, 's_info', sessionInfo())
}
```

**`pbmcapply::pbmclapply`** skips the *Matrix* and *MASS* packages,

```
> attributes(f1(1))$s_info
[...]
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2  parallel_4.3.2  tools_4.3.2     pbmcapply_1.5.1
```

whereas **`parallel::mclapply`** shows their use correctly.

```
> attributes(f2(1))$s_info
[...]
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.6-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-60     compiler_4.3.2  parallel_4.3.2  tools_4.3.2     grid_4.3.2     
[6] pbmcapply_1.5.1 lattice_0.22-5
```

**Info:** Using `pbmcapply_1.5.1` on `R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)/Ubuntu 22.04.3+6 LTS` and `R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)/AlmaLinux 9.2 (Turquoise Kodkod)`.

### Update

Just noticed, that this apparently also can happen with `parallel::mclapply`. How to get a reliable `sessionInfo` stored in my object when multithreading?